# How to cite multiple references at a time in Name Date format?

Tags: xetex, citing

I am new in latex. I am having problem in citing multiple paper/research work at a  time. I have explained it below.

In IEEE format research paper, we usually cite multiple references like this.

> Soundex is a nice algorithm **[3,4,19]**.

Or sometimes,

> Soundex is a nice algorithm **[3][4][19]**.

However, recently I am working on journal. They said, they allowed only *Author's name and date* style citation. Such as,

> This is a single citation **(John 2012)**.

However, they did not mention how to cite multiple references at a time. I need some idea, how to cite multiple references at a time in Name Date format.

In case you need, I have added some code from template.

```
\documentclass{nle}
............
............
......\cite{ref01}.
............
............
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[\protect\citename{Chaudhuri }2001]{ref01}
  Chaudhuri, B.B., “Reversed word dictionary and phonetically similar word grouping based spellchecker to Bangla text”, Proc. LESAL Workshop,Mumbai, 2001.
\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: *Usually,* `\cite{ref01,ref02}` should work and give a reasonable output. But what exactly happens depends on your citation/bibliography package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the natbib package

```
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
```

When I need to cite several articles, I use

```
\cite[]{DeAyala2009, Reckase2009}
```

or

```
\cite{DeAyala2009, Reckase2009}
```

depending whether you want the output in brackets or not.

At the end of the document, I provide a link to the bib file

`\bibliography{All}`

Comment: Instead of using empty brackets the `natbib` documentation recommends not to use `\cite` at all and instead recommends `\citet` or `\citep`. `\cite` is only kept around for backwards compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It really depents on citation/bibliography package, but a few examples using `biblatex` are:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
]{biblatex}
```

```
\textcite{ref1,ref2} did a great job doing whatever they did
```

**Author1 (year) and Author2 (year) did a great job doing whatever they did**

```
Other people did well too \parencite{ref3,ref4}
```

**Other people did well too (Author3 (year); Author4 (year))**